# BDD using Cucumber for a creating a Command Line Client Application

Tags: java, cucumber, command-line-interface, bdd

we are working on creating a command line client "tool" for conversion of certain types of files for our customers. We want to try and evaluate Behaviour Driven Development using Cucumber.
For this we need to be able use the Step Definitions file to invoke the CLI in the same way as a customer would invoke it.
Would appreciate any suggestions or ideas to do the same.

Are we doing the right thing as well, by expecting BDD to highlight the core usages of the CLI that we are developing ?

Comment: Could you add an example of what you want to achieve. Currently your question is a bit to broad. What is the customer supposed to add as parameter/environment/etc? What is the expected outcome by running your tool? (should there some files created, a specific text on stdout, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at aruba, links are docs and source-

https://app.cucumber.pro/projects/aruba/documents/branch/master/
https://github.com/cucumber/aruba